# iptables rules I can't do nothing

Tags: firewall, iptables, netfilter

I have this iptables configuration, it supposed to let me do ssh from remote machine in the same subnetwork, but I can't even do ping. What's happening?

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target      prot opt source     destination
ACCEPT      all  --  anywhere   anywhere
ACCEPT      all  --  anywhere   anywhere    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
WHITELIST   tcp  --  anywhere   anyrhere    tcp dpt:ssh
            tcp  --  anywhere   anywhere    tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source
LOG         all  --  anywhere   anywhere    recent: UPDATE seconds: 30 hit_count: 6 name: DEFAULT side: source LOG level warning
DROP        all  --  anywhere   anywhere    recent: UPDATE seconds: 30 hit_count: 6 name: DEFAULT side: source
ACCEPT      tcp  --  anywhere   anywhere    tcp dpt:ssh state NEW

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target      prot opt source     destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target      prot opt source     destination
ACCEPT      all  --  anywhere   anywhere    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain WHITELIST (1 references)
target      prot opt source             destination
RETURN      all  --  192.168.0.0/24     anywhere
RETURN      all  --  192.168.1.0/24     anywhere
RETURN      all  --  192.168.2.0/24     anywhere
RETURN      all  --  192.168.3.0/24     anywhere
DROP        all  --  anywhere           anywhere
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these rules, you only have SSH access from the some local networks. Everything else is forbidden, including ICMP, which is used by ping. 
With the following command you will  open access to your machine
"/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT" , but these restrictions are there with a reason so better consult your network administrator prior.